# Change keyboard input type to Uppercase in android

Tags: javascript, android, html, angularjs

I have a website with an input field in it

```
<input id = "code" type = "text"/>
```

I'm opening the website in WebView and I want that whenever this input is focussed, the keyboard should be opened in uppercase.

I tried modifying the input element like this

```
<input id = "code" type = "text" autocapitalize="characters" 
       style = "text-transform: uppercase;"/>
```

But then keyboard opens and only the first character is capitalized. After typing first character, the keyboard again turns to lowercase (though the value entered in textbox remains in uppercase).

So should I modify the HTML code in some other way or I have to do some explicit java coding so that the keyboard input type remains UPPERCASE for that input.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write that in javascript & enable javascript in android webview as

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```